# How to convert json containg different key value pairs to a list javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have a json string in the format

```
var jsonData =    [{"label":"Hass1(xxx_sem@hotmail.com)","value":"xxx_sem@hotmail.com"},{"label":"Hass(sxx_sem@hotmail.com)","value":"sxx_sem@hotmail.com"},{"label":"Sam(sx_sem@hotmail.com)","value":"sx_sem@hotmail.com"}]
```

i need to convert it in the format it into this way

```
var obj = {"Hass1(xxx_sem@hotmail.com)":"xxx_sem@hotmail.com",
          "Hass(sxx_sem@hotmail.com)","sxx_sem@hotmail.com"}
```

how to do so?

I have implemented so far like

```
function ConvertMeJason(jsonMe) {
            var list = JSON.parse(jsonMe);
            list.Object.forEach(function (obj) { /// I am getting error undefined function foreach
                emptyJson.add('"' + obj.label + '"', '"' + obj.value + '"');
            })
        }
```

Comment: Are the keys always going to be the same?  Like they will always be value or label?

Comment: Object.keys( list ).forEach()

Comment: yes they are same label and value

Comment: list.forEach, not list.Object.forEach

Comment: If bencripps solution dosen't, I have another solution, that is much much worse though.

Comment: FYI, what you posted as first example is not JSON. It's simply a JavaScript array. You may get the data from JSON, but that's not relevant for the problem.

Comment: let me implement but u can post ur solution too

Comment: `jsonData` contains an array, not a string representation of data in the JSON format. How do you call `ConvertMeJason`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function convert(data) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
        obj[data[i].label] = data[i].value;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4fpk448/).